# Badges, Update item number?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

Is it possible to update the badge number without sending the application a push notification?

Such as when the application is loaded you can change the badge number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  You can use this:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:3];
```

This will update the value without using a push notification.